# How to create custom extension use conditional rule functions

Tags: php, magento

I'm planning to build an extension like Shopping Cart, Price Rule, or Catalog Price Rule.

I've already tried to learn something from existing Magento code, that you can see on:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Promo/Quote/Edit/Tab/Conditions.php
```

To show a *Conditions Rule* field, I've tried to add this script, but it didn't work properly

```
$fieldset->addField('conditions', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'conditions',
        'label' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Conditions'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Conditions'),
    ))->setRule($model)->setRenderer(Mage::getBlockSingleton('rule/conditions'));
```

The question is:

1. How to display the conditional field properly on my custom field?
2. How to apply rule conditions on the front-end?

Thanks in advance.

update, 
take a look at my screenshot

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwLN4KpQhoGbU181R0ZKanJSdVE/edit?usp=drivesdk

this is my form.php:

```
<?php
class KS_Kscoba_Block_Adminhtml_Tcoba_Edit_Tab_Form 
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form

/*
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
*/
{
        protected function _prepareForm()
        {

                $model = Mage::registry('current_promo_quote_rule');
                $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
                $this->setForm($form);
                $fieldset = $form->addFieldset("kscoba_form", array("legend"=>Mage::helper("kscoba")->__("Item information")));


                        $fieldset->addField("kolom1", "text", array(
                        "label" => Mage::helper("kscoba")->__("Kolom 1"),
                        "name" => "kolom1",
                        ));

                         $fieldset->addField('kolom2', 'select', array(
                        'label'     => Mage::helper('kscoba')->__('Kolom 2'),
                        'values'   => KS_Kscoba_Block_Adminhtml_Tcoba_Grid::getValueArray1(),
                        'name' => 'kolom2',
                        ));

                /*
                problem start here
                */      

                $renderer = Mage::getBlockSingleton('adminhtml/widget_form_renderer_fieldset')
                    ->setTemplate('promo/fieldset.phtml')
                    ->setNewChildUrl($this->getUrl('*/promo_quote/newConditionHtml/form/rule_conditions_fieldset'));

                $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('conditions_fieldset', array(
                    'legend'=>Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products)')
                ))->setRenderer($renderer);

                $fieldset->addField('conditions', 'text', array(
                    'name' => 'conditions',
                    'label' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Conditions'),
                    'title' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Conditions'),
                ))->setRule($model)->setRenderer(Mage::getBlockSingleton('rule/conditions'));




                if (Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->getTcobaData())
                {
                    $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->getTcobaData());
                    Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setTcobaData(null);
                } 
                elseif(Mage::registry("tcoba_data")) {
                    $form->setValues(Mage::registry("tcoba_data")->getData());
                }
                return parent::_prepareForm();

        }
}
```

am I missing something?

Comment: hey Patrick thanks for the updates :)

Comment: question here: are you looking for 'my normal input field does not render in the form' or maybe 'how to create own renderer and apply it'? Would it be a problem for you to share your custom extension code through google drive (or alternative) link?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Conditions Field**

I may be overlooking another issue, but when I tested your `form.php`, the conditions field was missing because `Mage::registry('current_promo_quote_rule')` was undefined. The conditions field appeared on the page after I populated `$model` with a `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule` object.

Magento 1.8 registers the `current_promo_quote_rule` in `_initRule()` and `editAction()` of the `Mage_Adminhtml_Promo_QuoteController` (`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Promo/QuoteController.php`).

---

**2. Frontend**

Using shopping cart price rules as an example, the discounted price is applied in the frontend through the checkout module.

`Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php` has a `couponPostAction()` function which is called when the user submits a coupon code from the cart or checkout page. This function gets the cart's `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote` object, sets the coupon code on that object, and refreshes the totals of each item using the `collectTotals()` function of `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote`.

The quote object's `collectTotals()` gets the related `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address` objects and calls their `collectTotals()` functions. Those functions get each of the collector objects associated with the address and call its `collect()` method.

One of those collector objects is a `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Quote_Discount`, whose `collect()` method gets each `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` associated with this address, then calculates and stores its discount using a `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator`.

The specific logic in the conditions is read and applied deeper in the SalesRule module.